# What's the difference between InstallExecute and InstallFinalize actions in MSI?

Tags: windows-installer

In official MSI documentation, `InstallExecute` standard action is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as

> The InstallExecuteAgain action runs a script containing all operations
>   in the action sequence since either the start of the installation or
>   the last InstallExecuteAgain action or the last InstallExecute action.

Surprisingly, the `InstallFinalize` action, that is queued just after `InstallExecute` in all `MSI` files i have seen, is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) exactly the same!

> The InstallFinalize action runs a script that contains all operations
>   in the action sequence since either the start of the installation or
>   the execution of the InstallExecute or InstallExecuteAgain actions.

If i read documentation correctly, the `script` is actually and `installation script`. And it is executed only once. How it happens that two sequenced actions are documented to do exactly the same work to execute it and it is executed only once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`InstallExecute`, `InstallExecuteAgain`, and `InstallFinalize` all execute the installation script. The difference is that `InstallExecute` and `InstallExecuteAgain` let the transaction continue. So you can essentially "interrupt" the installation, do something else, and then let the installation continue by calling `InstallFinalize` if you're done or `InstallExecuteAgain` if you need to interrupt again.